# How to read the column using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to put a condition to print the revenue which is greater or equal to certain number using Pandas in Python.

I am using the code line" df[df.Total Revenue>=6678690.38]"

I am getting the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax." beacuse its not taking my column name(Total Revenue) with space. So how to read column if the column header is with space?

Note = df is where I am reading my file

Comment: please show us your exact code + error

Comment: In short, don't use the `df.xxx` notation but always `df['xxx']`, this will always work.

Comment: Wow , this worked. I used the header name with quotes , it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
df[df['Total Revenue']>=6678690.38]
```

Comment: Hi , Tried your suggestion but still got the same error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?"